# Facebook login using react create app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading, facebook-login, create-react-app

I made a React Webapp using the create-react-app module. Im trying to add in Facebook login but having issues.

I do not know where to load in the Facebook JavaScript SDK asynchronously to use FB.init, FB.getLoginStatus etc. I tried putting in a script tag in my index.html file and loading it like this:

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>


    <!-- <script src="./facebookLogin.js"></script>-->
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1830088130643938',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

but when I try to access the FB variable in index.js (starting point for create-react-app) it says FB' is not defined  no-undef".

I then tried loading it in the index.js file but again same problem:

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Importing CSS files
import './index.css';

// Importing components
import App from './App';
import FacebookButton from './components/facebookButton';

console.log("Running index.js right now");
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

console.log("FB is: ", FB);


ReactDOM.render(<FacebookButton/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It only works if I make a separate javascript file under public, link it through my index.html file and do all my facebook login there. But how do I access the FB variable from my index.js file using this?

I need the FB variable in index.js as thats the starting javascript file according to how create-react-app works. I wish to pass the FB variable down to my other components to make states, to handle clicks, login checks etc.

Maybe I might be not understanding how create-react-app works and how custom javascript or loading a JDK asynchronously can be done.

Please tell me how facebook login can be done with create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do facebook login is by using [react-facebook-login](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login). You can fine npm module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login)

Comment: I saw that module before but was just wondering how would one do it manually. I wanted to understand more how to load sdks and load them asynchronously in create-react-app.